# ASP.NET - Imageview just like in Google Picture Search Results

Tags: asp.net, google-image-search

Imagine, that u have 10 Imagelinks (Example of such a Link: [CLICK](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/uploads/monthly_05_2010/post-380028-12747928967239.jpg.pagespeed.ce.yRppR_j7ae.jpg)
What I want, is showing the 10 Pictures, googlelike (clickable) on my ASP.NET Website.

What would be, the best way to achieve this? 
Do I should use a Table? But what if the Image is bigger than the Rowsize and how I could do the Clickevent on it?.. and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a table if you want to keep the same number of images on each row. Otherwise, you could just display the images inline and allow them to word wrap naturally.

As far as large images, Google resizes the images so they fit. If you don't do that, then you could definitely have formatting problems.

Finally, you make them clickable the same way you make any image clickable: through an anchor tab, or using some type of client-side scripting. When you create the markup, you will need whatever data is required to make each image clickable in a meaningful way.